# How does this definition define a symbol $P$ outside the symbol set $S$ as a $S$-sentence?

Tags: logic, definition, first-order-logic

On [p126](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&lpg=PA126&pg=PA126#v=onepage&q&f=false)   in *§3.  Extensions by Definitions* in *VIII  Syntactic Interpretations and  Normal Forms* In Ebbinghaus' *Mathematical Logic*: $S$ is a (non-logical) symbol set

> 3.1  Definition.  Let $\Phi$  be a set of $S$-sentences.
>
> (a)  Suppose  $P \notin S$ is  an $n$-ary relation symbol and $\phi_P(v_0, ... , v_{n-1})$  an
> $S$-formula. Then we say that
> $$ \forall v_0, .... \forall v_{n-1} \quad (P v_0 ... n_{n-1} \leftrightarrow \phi_P(v_0, ... , v_{n-1})) $$
> is  an $S$-definition of $P$  in $\Phi$.

- How is $ \forall v_0, .... \forall v_{n-1} \quad (P v_0 ... n_{n-1} \leftrightarrow \phi_P(v_0, ... , v_{n-1})) $ a $S$-sentence or even a $S$-formula?
- $P v_0 ... n_{n-1}$ is on the left hand side of $\leftrightarrow$. Does that assume $P v_0 ... n_{n-1}$ to be a $S$-formula?
  But  $P \notin S$, so how can $P v_0 ... n_{n-1}$   be a $S$-formula?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save some writing, let's let $\sigma$ stand for $\forall v_0, \ldots, \forall v_{n-1} (Pv_0, \ldots, v_{n-1} \leftrightarrow \phi_P(v_0, \ldots, v_{n-1}))$.

You're correct that $\sigma$ is not an $S$-formula, because $\sigma$ involves the symbol $P$, which is not in $S$.  On the other hand, $\sigma$ is an $(S \cup \{P\})$-sentence.  That's kind of the point here: $\sigma$ is telling you that the symbol $P$, which is not in $S$, is equivalent to an $S$-formula.  The terminology "$S$-definition" refers to the fact that $\sigma$ defines $P$ in terms of $S$, it does not mean that $\sigma$ itself is an $S$-sentence.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "symbol , which is not in , is equivalent to an -formula"? Which " -formula"?

Comment: The $S$-formula $\phi_P$, which appears on the right side of the equivalence in $\sigma$.

Comment: "an -definition of  in Φ" sounds to say that it is in  Φ and therefore is an S-sentence.

Comment: I agree the naming is a bit unfortunate.  The "in $\Phi$" part appears in the next two parts of the definition (for $S$-definitions of functions and constants), and refers to $\Phi$ implying that the $S$-formulas $\phi_f$ and $\phi_c$ have the requisite properties (namely defining a function or having a unique witness, respectively).

Comment: Is it more accurate to say that (0,...,−1)) is an -definition of  in Φ, than to say that  is?

Comment: I've heard both.  While I personally prefer to call $\phi_P$ the $S$-definition, it looks like the book you're referring to is calling $\sigma$ an $S$-definition.

Comment: Do you see the concept of Syntactic Interpretation in some other mathematical logic books?

Comment: Is an -definition of  in Φ an interpretation of symbol P as an S'-sentence? (as part of a syntactic interpretation of S' in S' itself? c.f. p120)